# What does adding お at the end of a word change?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-を

An example would be: "watashi wa cake o(お) tabetai". What does the お do?
I tried on google translate and it seems it gives pertenence to that thing..like it belongs either to you or me..but I still need actual clarification.

Comment: I think what you mean is the so called direct object particle を (wo), which is pronounced like お.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three particles in Japanese which are typically spelled differently than they're pronounced:

1. は (pronounced *wa* rather than *ha*)
2. を (pronounced *o* rather than *wo*)
3. へ (pronounced *e* rather than *he*)

Although you're hearing it correctly, in this case it is actually the particle を, marking a direct object:

> （わたしは）**ケーキを**　たべたい

This particle comes directly after the word or phrase it marks, like particles usually do in Japanese.

---

We have direct objects in English, too.  But in English, we don't have a particle like を.  Instead, we mark direct objects with word order:

> **I** want to eat **the cake**.

Here, we can tell ***I*** is the subject, and ***the cake*** is the direct object.  Why?  Because of their location.  If we switch them, the meaning changes completely:

> **The cake** wants to eat **me**.

Japanese word order is much more free than in English, because the Japanese language has little words like を and doesn't have to rely on word order all the time.

Comment: We do mark pronouns as accusative (as actually comes up in your example ^_^) - 'I' translates to 私が or 私は, 'me' translates to 私を (and sometimes just 私).

Comment: @Sjiveru That's true!  I deliberately avoided talking about the last remnants of the English case system, though, because I was trying to keep the answer simple, and because I think word order is a much stronger marker.  "Me and him are going to the store later."  "It was I who killed the man."  And of course, the accusative-nominative contrast exists only for pronouns, so it doesn't help for our example of "the cake".

Comment: Reasonable reasons for leaving it out!